# Analytics privilege earned long after reaching 25,000 reputation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, privileges, site-analytics

Today when I logged into SO, I have observed notification saying I got "analytics" privilege.

I was not aware of what it is, so browsed to the tag. Description saying it would be awarded for users with 25,000 reputation. I have around 45,000 reputation as of today and I got this privilege today, is this bug?

**My reputation and notification**
[image: My reputation and notification]

**Site Analytics privilege description**
[image: Site Analytics privilege description]

Comment: Not a bug, the feature just wasn't completed until recently.

Comment: @HansPassant:  
i think wording should be changed to say something like, 'user who has at least 25,000 reputation' instead of 'Awarded at 25,000 reputation' which will avoid this confusion.

Comment: Hmm, it will work just fine for the next fifty years.

Comment: Why on earth has this been down voted?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This privilege was just created yesterday, so it was impossible to have earned it before then. The privilege notification will be generated for every user who has at least 25,000 reputation at the next reputation change on their account.

Comment: i think wording should be changed to say something like you described, 'user who has at least 25,000 reputation' instead of 'Awarded at 25,000 reputation'

Comment: @Nambari why? Why not be consistent with the others? This only affects users with above-the-limit rep when a new privilege is added, and it seems reasonable to assume that 25k+ users know the site's features well enough to figure it out!